# Rating - Ant Design for Vue.js different icon for each

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ant-design-vue

I need to do something similar as we have for React on Ant Design. I mean this: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/edit/master/components/rate/demo/character-function.tsx

but in Vue.js

Im pretty new with Vue and in our project we decided to do something similar to this: https://support.nicereply.com/article/255-rating-scales-available-in-nicereply

see NPS. I wanted to ask you if it is even possible to do something in Vue. For now I tried to play a little but only thing I was able to do was a not an 11 item scale but 11 rows with different icons each 11 scale. Im lost.

I saw that they allow to use slots but when I tried with slots only thing I achieved was 11 rows with same icon, not one row with 11 differen icons.

Can somebody help me?